# Wget with a special character inside the URL

Tags: encoding, wget

I download an HTML page and its files via Wget on Windows:

```
wget -m -k -p -np --html-extension
```

That HTML content has a lot of URLs with special characters (example: `<a href="chp1_資料庫概論.doc" target="_blank">Chp1</a>`).

There are two issues:

1. Inside the HTML content, URLs (including special character's) become some random words:

   Expectation:

   ```
   <a href="chp1_資料庫概論.doc" target="_blank">Chp1</a>
   ```

   Actual:

   ```
   <a href="http://acupun.site/lecture/database/chp1_%B8%EA%AE%C6%AEw%B7%A7%BD%D7.doc" target="_blank">Chp1</a>
   ```
2. Filename is random words.

   The second issue can be solved by adding `--restrict-file-names=nocontrol`.

   How do I solve the first one? Is this Windows version a problem?

   Obviously, inside HTML, it converts URLs with special characters to something...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that Windows will still treat your UTF-8 characters as Latin-1 characters, even with the `--restrict-file-names=nocontrol` command line argument.

GNU's site documents this bug [here](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?37564), and it is still unfortunately an issue for Windows users to this day. Your command would work inside a Linux environment however.